# custom function to show wordpress posts returns only one post

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function who_we_work_with(){
    $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
    query_posts('cat=41&showposts=4');
    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $myposts = get_posts('posts_per_page=10&offset=$debut');
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
            $output='<a href="'. get_the_permalink().'">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding_right0 csr_activities_news" style="background:url(' .$image[0].');background-size:cover;">';
        endif; 
        $output.='<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 csr_news"></div></div></a>';
    endwhile;

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode("who_we_work_with", "who_we_work_with");
```

Comment: First can you add more explanation, what you need, what is the intended use of the function, where are you using it etc. Second: never use `query_posts()`. Use either `get_posts()` or `WP_Query()`.

Comment: I want this function to display the latest 4 posts but it just displays only one post

Comment: Maybe you have only 1 post in the category with the id 41?

Comment: no I have 8 posts in that category

Comment: Why you're querying posts in the category 41 then use `get_post`s **in the loop** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1.
If you must use the code you are trying, which is not best approach by the way, for that see #2 point.  You see in your current code you are overwriting your PHP variable on ever loop iteration, so it is being reset every time, that's why you only get LAST post value/data, to fix that change this:

```
$output = '<\a href="'. get_the_permalink().'">
```

to

```
$output.= '<a href="'. get_the_permalink().'">
```

See the dot just before `=` sign.

2.
For better code I suggest use something like this:

```
function who_we_work_with(){
        $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'no-paging' => true,    
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
          if (has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() ) ){
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
                $output.='<a href="'. get_the_permalink().'">
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding_right0 csr_activities_news" style="background:url(' .$image[0].');background-size:cover;">';
                            $output.=  get_the_title(); 
            }
            $output.='<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 csr_news"></div></div></a>';
        endwhile;
        endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    return $output;
    }
```

Comment: sorry having hard time to send formatted code in option#2

Comment: You need to use two tabulations : one for the list indent, and one for the code indent. The code button doesn't work as expected for that so you'll have to manually put the two tabulations by copy/paste them.

Comment: Hi @vard & Dingo_d thank you to guide and help me with formatting!

Comment: LOL i cannot comment on question's comments as I need 50 points it says. So could not add "." notation issue original code had which was overwriting the $output variable data.

Comment: @Moshin That was indeed part of the problem, but making a full answer to show how not to use `query_posts` will be more usefull to OP that just a comment. As a note, you may want to add `$output = '';` just before the loop, as it is now the variable is not initialized.

Comment: Vard, i cannot yet post comments to original questions. Sorry

Comment: @Moshin Yes but you can edit your own answer to add this inside your code :)

Comment: Thank you @Mohsin the  .(dot) did the trick .thank you so much.

Comment: @PramodSR Happy to know that it helped.